# How to dim screen according to time in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I know may be this is the duplicate post but I didn't get exact answer yet please tell me if any one know this .

my need is I want to create dim scrren function in my android application suppose my application ideal for 30 second so my screen should dim and if I am touch the screen so again screen becaome bright please help me

Answer (score 4):

```
int Time_delay=30000;
Runnable screentimeout= new Runnable() 
{
   public void run() 
   {
       WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
       lp.screenBrightness = 1.0f;

       getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
   }
 }
```

After 30 seconds the screen brightness will be dim.
This will help you to detect the user interaction between Activity
In your Activity

```
Handler hl_timeout = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle b)
{
   hl_timeout.postDelayed(screentimeout, Time_delay); // The screentimeout will be triggered after 30sec
}
```

There's a function to detect User Interaction.Use that

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          hl_timeout.removeCallbacks(screentimeout);
          hl_timeout.postDelayed(screentimeout, Time_delay);    
}
```

Comment: @ sridhr how i can detect device in on ideal state or running state pelase tell me

Comment: You can implement onTouchListener to the layout and run the thread if there is no touch event occurred.

Comment: No Sridhar this might be very complicated , we need to find some override methods for this.

Comment: Yes this detect user interaction but i want that method which detect idle condition

Comment: Please check the updated one and let me know if??

Comment: This giving error and eclipse give suggestion make it handler Boolean .

Comment: Hey Sridahr gud concept now its working you are rock .

Comment: Thank you... its pleasure to hear this.